# Installing Git on CentOS

Tags: git, centos

How install git on CentOS? I find this [manual](http://www.how-to-linux.com/2009/01/install-git-161-on-centos-52/). Is it good?

Comment: Not programming question - and have you tried? It looks fine.

Comment: This is the server on which the application is running right now, so I'm afraid to experiment.

Answer (score 9):

```
yum install gettext-devel expat-devel curl-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf git-1.7.5.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.5
make prefix=/usr/local all
make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, then install it using yum.

Answer (score 4):

yum install git-core

Comment: No Match for argument: git-core

Comment: You need to add repository, here's how to do this: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

Answer (score 1):

Note everyone: git comes in the stranded centos 6 repos but for 5 you will need EPEL or freshmeat etc or from source.

Answer (score 0):

I provide RPMs for git 1.7 in the Webtatic repository, as the kernel.org RPM's are incompatible with CentOS's old rpm installer.

http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/09/git-on-centos-5/